# SharePoint 2010 and Firefox/Safari, will Kerberos work?

Tags: sharepoint, firefox, safari, sharepoint-2010, kerberos

As far as I know both FireFox and Safari can not work with Kerberos in a SharePoint context for the time being, but why is that, and should we expect that both FireFox and Safari will play ball in the SharePoint 2010 timeframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All information on SharePoint 2010 is currently under NDA until late October (except what you can see on the [sneak peek](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/2010/)) so no-one will be able to officially answer your question at this time.

However there is very unlikely to be any difference for the 2010 version from SharePoint 2007. Kerberos is supported by the product but its actual behaviour within a Windows network is determined by the current implementation used in Windows Server today. This is not related to SharePoint but the use of Kerberos within IIS ASP.NET applications. So don't expect anything to change here on the server side.

For the client side, that's entirely dependent on the development priorities in the Firefox and Safari teams. For Firefox, [search for](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&content=firefox+kerberos) and vote on the bugs with Kerberos you'd like fixed. You may be able to contribute and assist with the fixes as well.

Comment: +1 Kerberos and integrated authentication limitations are Windows-wide, not SharePoint-specific.

Comment: The NDA has expired for SharePoint 2010, starting with Beta 2.